# string extract with pySpark

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, extract

I have a column `targeting` in spark df. The values look like this:

```
ab=px_d_1200;ab=9;ab=t_d_o_1000;artid=delish.recipe.46338;artid=delish_recipe_46338;avb=85;cat=recipes;role=3;sect=cooking
ab=px_d_1200;ab=8;ab=t_d_o_1000;apn=640x480_370;artid=delish.recipe.25860457;artid=delish_recipe_25860457;avb=90;cat=recipes;clc=chicken-breast-recipes;clc=insanely-easy-chicken-dinners;clc=weeknight-dinners;embedid=a6311e94-3b66-4712-8fca-eaa423e4e69a;gs_cat=response_check;gs_cat=gl_english;role=3;sect=cooking;sub=recipe-ideas;tool=recipe;urlhash=5425cac3a9c2959917d0634f5bd6d842
```

I need to extract role=X. Also, the value after the equal sign I need to save in another column.
The desired output is:

```
role
3
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a working solution for you

**Create the Dataframe here**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"ab=px_d_1200;ab=9;ab=t_d_o_1000;artid=delish.recipe.46338;artid=delish_recipe_46338;avb=85;cat=recipes;role=3;sect=cooking")],[ "col1","col2"])
df.show(truncate=False)
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                                                                                                      |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |ab=px_d_1200;ab=9;ab=t_d_o_1000;artid=delish.recipe.46338;artid=delish_recipe_46338;avb=85;cat=recipes;role=3;sect=cooking|
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

df_new = df.filter(F.col("col2").contains("role"))
df_new = df_new.withColumn("split_col", F.explode(F.split(F.col("col2"), ";")))
df_new = df_new.filter(F.col("split_col").contains("role"))
df_new = df_new.withColumn("final_col", (F.split(F.col("split_col"), "=")))
df_new = df_new.withColumn("role", F.element_at(F.col('final_col'), -1).alias('role'))
df_new.show()

+----+--------------------+---------+---------+----+
|col1|                col2|split_col|final_col|role|
+----+--------------------+---------+---------+----+
|   1|ab=px_d_1200;ab=9...|   role=3|[role, 3]|   3|
+----+--------------------+---------+---------+----+
```

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: great that it helped you .. :) would appreciate if you could upvote as well